# Laravel 5 / Nginx - strange behavior of CORS headers set at web server level

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, http-headers, cors

I am facing up this problem:

I set CORS headers in nginx, in this way:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,Cache-Control,Content-Type";
```

I need to call my API endpoint to authenticate an user and release a JWT. What is happening is that if the authentication goes fine, the server respond with the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Thu, 17 Mar 2016 17:13:34 GMT
Server →nginx
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=10886400; includeSubdomains
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

But, **if credentials are invalid, I get these ones**:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Thu, 17 Mar 2016 17:14:58 GMT
Server →nginx
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding
```

In other words, **correct credentials give me a 200 status code with CORS headers, while wrong credentials give me 401 status code *without* CORS headers**

Here is the auth method of User controller:

```
public function authenticate(Requests\AuthenticateUserRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
        $customClaims = ['tfa' => null];

        try
        {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims))
            {
                // when this is the response, CORS headers are not set by nginx 
                return response()->json(Utils::standardResponse(false, 'Invalid credentials'), 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e)
        {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(Utils::standardResponse(false, 'Could not create token'), 500);
        }

       [...email notification and other stuff...]

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(Utils::standardResponse(true, '', compact('token')));
    }
```

**N.B. i am testing with Postman, but the actual problem is that without CORS headers I can't read the response in browser (which uses XHR through React `fetch`)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out. Nginx `add_header` does set headers **only on successful responses** (200 status code).

I did need to use [headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) nginx's module. In particular, I did:

```
more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT";
more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,Cache-Control,Content-Type";
```

As suggested in the documentation,

> If either -s or -t is not specified or has an empty list value, then
>   no match is required. Therefore, the following directive set the
>   Server output header to the custom value for **any** status code and **any**
>   content type:
>
> `more_set_headers    "Server: my_server";`

Comment: when nginx version <1.7.5 only 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307 works,when >=1.7.5 you can always ,quote from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414669/nginx-add-headers-when-returning-400-codes