# NGINX Cannot handle bad requests

Tags: php, nginx

So this is the first time i use NGINX for anything. I have 2 CentOs 7 VMs - one with NGINX and one with APACHE.
On both i have the default configurations.
I have the same php page on both. I try pushing GET request with incorrect header to both. 
Apache response is error 400 Bad Request - which is great.
NGINX on the other hand discloses the php in plain text.

I am looking for a way to secure this in NGINX and make it so if there is incorrect header to return error 400.
I hope someone can advise where i can configure this.

Comment: Can you post your nginx configuration? If nginx is returning the PHP code it's very possible that you haven't configured it to use a PHP interpreter such as php-fpm so it's treating php files as plaintext

Answer (score 0):

For returning headers, it has already been answered, so you can put the header wherever you want:

[nginx add headers when returning 400 codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414669/nginx-add-headers-when-returning-400-codes)

But if what you want is to handle the error with a custom page so you don't see the whole php page, you can have custom .html pages for each error. This DO guide will help you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I want to return 400 if the header is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

By default Nginx just ignores invalid headers. If you want it to return 400 instead then you need to include this directive in your config:

`ignore_invalid_headers off;`

This can either be at http or server level, but as per the docs:

> If the directive is specified on the server level, its value is only
>   used if a server is a default one. The value specified also applies to
>   all virtual servers listening on the same address and port.

Comment: So i did try that. I added "ignore_invalid_headers off;" to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf under http, but still the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add if the header is empty i get what i need - 400 Bad Request. But if i enter anything different than the server hostname in header i get the issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK so i solved my issue. Here is the solution..
In the server block i had this:

```
 server {
listen       80 default_server;
server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
```

i had to remove **default_server** and there we go.