# Getting custom error message using fetch api when http response status is 400

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

I have Python Flask (v 1.0.0) backend that returns an http response with status 400 and a custom error message

```
return Response('My custom errror message', 400)
```

In my frontend I have an API call to the backend using Fetch API:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Since 400 is a `BAD REQUEST`, `fetch` goes straight to `catch` and all I have is `TypeError: Failed to fetch` message.

How can I get my custom error message in frontend instead of `Failed to fetch` message? It is visible in the DevTools, so I hope it should be available in `fetch` somehow?

[image][image]

Comment: have you tried accessing response code in ``then`` block?

Comment: it goes straight to `.catch`, I think because it is a 400 response and `fetch` treats it as an error instantly.

Comment: Try this github.com/github/fetch/issues/203#issuecomment-143347675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was nginx configuration issue. I was right when I said that fetch goes straight to `.catch` when the response is 400 but the reason was that the request was actually failing - I was seeing a CORS error in the console.
After adding `always` parameter to my nginx configuration, there are no more CORS errors and I can access `My custom error message` inside `.then` and it no longer goes straight to `.catch`. 
More details here: [nginx add headers when returning 400 codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414669/nginx-add-headers-when-returning-400-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch won't throw an exception in case of status out of 200-299 range. You are trying to parse plain text ("My custom error message") as a json and that's the cause of exception. You have to check `response.status` before calling `json()`

Comment: tldr: call `text()` instead of `json()` for `response.status === 400`

Comment: even if I change my first `.then` to `.then(response => console.log(response.status))` it goes straight to `.catch` - first `.then` isn't even executed