# Proxy Server - Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present (First request works, second request doesn't)

Tags: ajax, nginx, axios, cors, reverse-proxy

I have a proxy server which I use for masking the domain, and it loads assets (When user visits `server.com`, through nginx, it's actually directing to `server.com/123123`).

The http requests works, however I am having a problem with ajax requests.

- So, when I visit example.com, website works
- When I do first POST (with ajax) request, it works (https://server.com/ajax/marketing/ajax/recaptcha/validate)
- When I do second POST request (ajax), it doesn't work and says *"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://server.com/ajax/validate-order/H123HKK' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."*

In my server nginx (server.com), I have these headers:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
```

In my example.com nginx, I have added:

```
proxy_set_header Host server.com;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443 ssl;

   server_name example.com;

   location = / {
       proxy_pass https://server.com/123123;
   }

   #Certs
   #ssl_certificate y.pem;
   #ssl_certificate_key x.pem;
}
```

My backend is Laravel however I am not sure if it's related to that.

What am I doing wrong so that one POST request works but other one doesn't? `/validate-order/{orderId}` should return a json so may that be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently nginx doesn't add headers to error response codes; and there is a way to force it to `add_header` always

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' * always;
```

Adding "always" keyword to all headers in my server, it worked!

Big thanks to [akawhy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416736/4705339).

Comment: I have to say, I spent quite some time googling before finding that it's because the error code :) thx

Comment: @cvakiitho yeah, I feel you :)